# c++ template type deduction : How to convert the T to const T

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I need to define a functions using macro based on the type of a structure member.

Eg:

```
struct A {
    uint32_t value;  // need to define a function return uint32_t
    uint8_t  str[0]; // need to define a function returning const uint8_t *
};
```

I need to define the following functions -

```
uint32_t fun () {...}
const uint8_t *fun () {...}  << note the pointer types needs a const
```

First Attempt:

Use std::decay_t to decay the array type to pointer to be used as return type : `std::decay_t<decltype(A::str)> fun () {...}`

But this doesn't work for the non-standard 0 length array as above. I cannot change the definition of the structure due to political reasons. So I have to live with zero length array.

Second Attempt:
Deduce the return type as below:

```
template<class T>
struct decay_zero { using type = std::decay_t<T>; };

template<class T>
struct decay_zero<T[]> { using type = const T *; };

template<class T, size_t N>
struct decay_zero<T[N]> { using type = const T *; }; // adding const to pointer type

template<class T>
struct decay_zero<T[0]> { using type = const T *; };

template<class T>
struct return_type {
private:
        using U = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
public:
        using type = decay_zero<U>::type;
};

return_type<decltype(A::str)>::type fun {...}
```

This works on GCC but doesn't work on CLANG for some reason. CLANG complains that return-type is array for zero length array. why?

Third Attempt:

So my third attempt is this - declare a 'decay' function as below. I have separate definition for pointer type and non-pointer type so that I can add
the "const" to pointer types

```
template <
             typename T,
             typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr
         >
const T __decayFunction (const T t) // making it const T
{
    return return t;
}

template <
             typename T,
             typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr
         >
decltype(auto) __decayFunction (T t)
{
    return t;
}

template<class T>
struct return_type {
private:
        using U = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
public:
        using type = decltype(__decayFunction(std::declval<U>()));
};

return_type<decltype(A::str)>::type fun() { ... }
```

But I see that the return type of the above function is not const.

How to make it a const?

Comment: Zero-sized array is not allowed in C++

Comment: I know but it is a GCC and CLANG extension and I have to live it - as it is part of legacy code.

Comment: It's [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), not CLANG (or CLang).

Comment: And I guess its gcc and not GCC

Answer (score 0):

The following works -

```
template <typename T>
const T *as_const_ptr (const T *p)
{
    return p;
}

template <
             typename T,
             typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr
         >
auto __decayFunction (T t) -> decltype(as_const_ptr(t)) { return as_const_ptr(t); }

template <
             typename T,
             typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr
         >
decltype(auto) __decayFunction (T t)  { return t; }

template<class T>
struct return_type {
private:
        using U = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
public:
        using type = decltype(__decayFunction(std::declval<U>()));
};
```

Comment: I am not sure. Hence I have not accepted the answer :-) I am waiting for a template expert to explain. T when passed as function argument is deduced as a pointer type. so w/ char a[10], T will be char *, adding a const to somehow is ignored. The following also works, where the function signature is T *

`template <typename T>
const T* __decayFunction (const T* t)  { return t; }`